# In python, accessing global variables of one file in another

Tags: python

I have two python scripts, one of which contains a global variable *globVar* which I wish to use in another file. The file structures are as follows:

**File1.py**

```
from File2 import *

globVar = []

def func1(a,b):
  globVar.append(range(a,b))
  printLast()

def main():
  for i in range(1,10):
    for j in range(1,5):
      func1(i,j)

if __name__=="__main__":
  main()
```

**File2.py**

```
from File1 import globVar

def printLast():
  element = globVar[-1]
  print 'Latest element is ',element
```

Dont' bother with the productivity of code, it's just an example to sample the problem at hand.

On running the script *File1.py*, an error pops up, that *globVar[-1]* is **list index out of range**. Or simply, the **list is empty**.

Why is so?

**Edit** :

This question, as was initially posted, contained *"from File2 import printLast"* as the first line of **File1.py**. But that syntax was resulting in ImportError as was pointed out by *@user2357112* in comments.

Now that it has been changed to *from File2 import **, the error is IndexError, which I was trying to point out to begin with.

Any reasonable explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: Because, you are importing just globVar variable, not initializing it. if you want to use initialized globVar then you should run main() func in the File2.py file

Comment: Aside from the syntax errors and misspelled function names (`lastPrint` instead of `printLast`), this code also has a circular import problem that would cause an `ImportError` before the `IndexError` could occur. [When you post code to show your problem, please actually run what you post to verify that it correctly shows the problem.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @user2357112 Correcto. Pardon, the rookie mistakes. Though I believed this sample code would emulate the gist of my problem, it doesn't. Shall take care of such things in future.

Comment: @user2357112 Another thing. When I changed _from File2 import printLast_ to _from File2 import *_, the error has changed to IndexError rather than Import Error as was initially the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the main module `File1.py` executed directly from the python is special, and when you import it, it is actually created a second time, so there are 2 `globVar`s. See: http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#executing-the-main-module-twice

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the if statement in the File1.py at the end, this will work fine. Like this:

**File1.py**

```
globVar = []

def func1(a,b):
    globVar.append(range(a,b)
    printLast()

def main():
    for i in range(1,10):
        for j in range(1,5):
            func1(i,j)

globVar = main()
```

This will ensure that globVar will have the array of values.

Comment: It's not returning anything in `main`